# My findViewByid turn red on extend fragment, im doing on onCreate method not in onCreateView method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

find view by id marked red, I'm not doing it to onCreateView, help me to solve this kind of error, I'm really new in android programming

```
package com.example.mymonitoring;

public class MonitoringFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = "STATISTICACTIVITY";
private Button Temperature;
private Button Humidity;
private TextView t1;
private TextView t2;
private static TextView t3;
private static final String THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_ID = "572138";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_API_KEY = "ND76MAN2CWQJG25G"; //GARBAGE KEY
private static final String THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_STRING = "ND76MAN2CWQJG25G";
/* Be sure to use the correct fields for your own app*/
private static final String THINGSPEAK_FIELD1 = "field1";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_FIELD2 = "field2";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_FIELD3 = "field3";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_UPDATE_URL = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_URL = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/";
private static final String THINGSPEAK_FEEDS_LAST = "/feeds/last?";

private ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel;
private ThingSpeakLineChart tsChart;
private LineChartView chartView;

public MonitoringFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return v;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempNumber);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidNumber);


        ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel = new ThingSpeakChannel(572138);
        tsChannel.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
                // Make use of your Channel feed here!
                // Show Channel ID and name on the Action Bar
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(channelName);
                // Notify last update time of the Channel feed through a Toast message
                Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
                //Toast.makeText(MonitoringFragment.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        tsChannel.loadChannelFeed();


        Temperature = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTemperature);
        Humidity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHumidity);


        Temperature.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                findViewById(R.id.TemperatureLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.HumidityLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);


                final LineChartView chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.TempChart);
                tsChart = new ThingSpeakLineChart(572138, 1);
                tsChart.setListener(new ThingSpeakLineChart.ChartDataUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChartDataUpdated(long channelId, int fieldId, String title, LineChartData lineChartData, Viewport maxViewport, Viewport initialViewport) {

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);

                        tsChart.setNumberOfEntries(200);
                        // Set value axis labels on 10-unit interval
                        tsChart.setValueAxisLabelInterval(10);
                        // Set date axis labels on 5-minute interval
                        tsChart.setDateAxisLabelInterval(1);
                        // Show the line as a cubic spline
                        tsChart.useSpline(true);
                        // Set the line color
                        tsChart.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                        // Set the axis color
                        tsChart.setAxisColor(Color.parseColor("#455a64"));
                        // Set the starting date (5 minutes ago) for the default viewport of the chart
                        tsChart.setChartStartDate(calendar.getTime());

                        chartView.setLineChartData(lineChartData);
                        chartView.setMaximumViewport(maxViewport);
                        chartView.setCurrentViewport(initialViewport);
                    }
                });
                tsChart.loadChartData();

                try {
                    new FetchThingspeakTempTask().execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }

        });



    Humidity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findViewById(R.id.HumidityLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.TemperatureLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);


            final LineChartView chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.HumidChart);
            tsChart = new ThingSpeakLineChart(572138, 2);
            tsChart.setListener(new ThingSpeakLineChart.ChartDataUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChartDataUpdated(long channelId, int fieldId, String title, LineChartData lineChartData, Viewport maxViewport, Viewport initialViewport) {

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);

                    tsChart.setNumberOfEntries(200);
                    // Set value axis labels on 10-unit interval
                    tsChart.setValueAxisLabelInterval(10);
                    // Set date axis labels on 5-minute interval
                    tsChart.setDateAxisLabelInterval(1);
                    // Show the line as a cubic spline
                    tsChart.useSpline(true);
                    // Set the line color
                    tsChart.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#056604"));
                    // Set the axis color
                    tsChart.setAxisColor(Color.parseColor("#455a64"));
                    // Set the starting date (5 minutes ago) for the default viewport of the chart
                    tsChart.setChartStartDate(calendar.getTime());

                    chartView.setLineChartData(lineChartData);
                    chartView.setMaximumViewport(maxViewport);
                    chartView.setCurrentViewport(initialViewport);
                }
            });
            tsChart.loadChartData();
            try {
                new FetchThingspeakHumidTask().execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }


        }

    });
}

public class FetchThingspeakTempTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        t1.setText("Fetching Data from Server.Please Wait...");
    }
    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_URL + THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_ID +
                    THINGSPEAK_FEEDS_LAST + THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_STRING + "=" +
                    THINGSPEAK_API_KEY + "");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            //Toast.makeText(MonitoringFragment.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject channel = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
            double v1 = channel.getDouble(THINGSPEAK_FIELD1);
            String field1 = Double.toString(v1);
            t1.setText(field1);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class FetchThingspeakHumidTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        t2.setText("Fetching Data from Server.Please Wait...");
    }
    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_URL + THINGSPEAK_CHANNEL_ID +
                    THINGSPEAK_FEEDS_LAST + THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_STRING + "=" +
                    THINGSPEAK_API_KEY + "");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
           // Toast.makeText(MonitoringFragment.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject channel = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
            double v2 = channel.getDouble(THINGSPEAK_FIELD2);
            String field2 = new Double(v2).toString();
            t2.setText(field2);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```

this my xml code, fragment_monitoring.xml, findviewById marked red,  doing it on onCreate method in extend fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.mymonitoring.MonitoringFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGreyTransparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/statsLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

    </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_stats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTemperature"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Temperature" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHumidity"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Humidity" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="449dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TemperatureLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include layout="@layout/tempdisplay" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Current Temperature :"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tempNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="........"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Suggestion:"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/suggestionTemp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="........"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/HumidityLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <include layout="@layout/humiddisplay" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Current Humidity :"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/humidNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="........"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Suggestion:"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/suggestionHumid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="........"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what your question is. It sort of looks like you want someone to debug your code for you, which is not going to get much traction here. You should [edit] this question and tell us what you are trying to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you got. Mention any research you've done. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments have no `findViewById()` method, so it's red because it doesn't exist.

`findViewById()` *must* be called on a View object or from an Activity (which is just a proxy to the root View of that Activity).

You also can't call `findViewById()` in the `onCreate()` method of a Fragment anyway, because `onCreate()` is executed before `onCreateView()`, meaning the Fragment's View is null at that point.

`v` also doesn't seem to be a variable in your Fragment.

Move your code to `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` and make the `findViewById()` calls on your View.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `findViewById()` inside of a Fragment, not an activity. Fragment does not have a `findViewById()` method that you can call. You will have to call it on your view like so:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.testId)
```

If you don't have a view for your fragment, you must inflate one in `onCreateView()`. Keep in mind that `onCreate()` will get called before `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

On fragments, to use that method you have to call it from the parent View where it would find the id.

Also you have to take into account that the view is created after onCreateView, so you won't find anything on onCreate because that method is called before onCreateView.

So you should search the views on onCreateView doing something like this

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monitoring, container, false);
    TextView tempNumberTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.tempNumber)
    return root;
}
```